# Getting a single object from mongodb in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I've picked up a piece of code that is using the MongoDB driver like this to get a single object from a collection...this can't be right, can it?  Is there a better way of getting this?

```
IMongoCollection<ApplicationUser> userCollection;
....
userCollection.FindAsync(x => x.Id == inputId).Result.ToListAsync().Result.Single();
```

Answer (score 31):

Yes, there is.

First of all don't use `FindAsync`, use `Find` instead. On the `IFindFluent` result use the `SingleAsync` extension method and await the returned task inside an async method:

```
async Task MainAsync()
{
    IMongoCollection<ApplicationUser> userCollection = ...;

    var applicationUser = await userCollection.Find(_ => _.Id == inputId).SingleAsync();
}
```

The new driver uses async-await exclusively. Don't block on it by using `Task.Result`.

Comment: Also, rather than having to catch the `InvalidOperationException` on a miss consider `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `SingleAsync()`

Comment: @KCD `Single` enforces there's only a single matching item and no more. Using `First` can hide data errors. If you want to support a case when there's not even a single matching item you can use `SingleOrDefaultAsync`

Comment: I'm using the latest driver. Should we do Find+SingleAsync, or FindAsync+SingleAsync, or is it the same thing in the end?

Answer (score 8):

You should limit your query before executing, otherwise you will first find all results and then only read one of it.

You could either specify the limit using [`FindOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2.htm) in [`FindAsync`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1_1.htm), or use the [fluent syntax](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm) to limit the query before executing it:

```
var results = await userCollection.Find(x => x.Id == inputId).Limit(1).ToListAsync();
ApplicationUser singleResult = results.FirstOrDefault();
```

The result from [`ToListAsync`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions_ToListAsync__1.htm) will be a list but since you limited the number of results to 1, that list will only have a single result which you can access using Linq.

Comment: Why do you use limit in query with condition by primary key? Why do you use ToListAsync and then FirstOrDefault? I don't understand who could upvote this answer.

Comment: @rnofenko (1) `Id` is not guaranteed to be a primary key I think. (2) I was not aware of the existence of `IFindFluentExtensions`, as such I couldn’t know about `SingleAsync`. (3) The implementation behind `SingleAsync` does use a limit too. (4) `ToListAsync` is one way to execute an `IFindFluent` query and simpler to use than the cursor. (5) `ToListAsync` still returns a list, so if you want to get the actual item, you need to access that first, e.g. using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @rnofenko I know about `_id` but after reading through the documentation I found no proof yet that this is always mapped to the `Id` property in .NET. Instead, I have something that suggests that [this does not always need to be the case](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonIdAttribute.htm).

Comment: Id Mapping documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#the-id-member

Comment: Note that `.Find(...).FirstOrDefault()` is already provided, and it does a `.Limit(1)` under the covers: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/45c67f553f7e1bf820e5a50b9cf8e581e6bd9bdf/src/MongoDB.Driver/IFindFluentExtensions.cs#L213-L218

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of MongoDB Find() is deprecated, so you can either use

```
collection.FindSync(o => o.Id == myId).Single()
```

or

```
collection.FindAsync(o => o.Id == myId).Result.Single()
```

You can also use `SingleOrDefault()`, which returns null if no match was found instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the method:

```
coll.Find(_ => _.Id == inputId).SingleAsync();
```

To work as I was getting the error

`InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element c#`

So I ended up using `.FirstOrDefault()`

**Example:**

```
public FooClass GetFirstFooDocument(string templatename)
        {
            var coll = db.GetCollection<FooClass>("foo");
            FooClass foo = coll.Find(_ => _.TemplateName == templatename).FirstOrDefault();
            return foo; 
        }
```